# Batch File Problems - Batch Game Code Error in Running, but runs fine Outside in CMD.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Geo here, I have a command (Kinda Confuzzling) that isn't working. It works outside of the batch file fine though! All the Parameters are set, and i would prefer it on one line (Which it should work on). It doesn't work in a batch file, but in CMD works perfectly

Here is the command:

```
IF %Move%==North IF %0x-1Seen%==1 (set LevelXY=0x1 & GOTO :Level1~0x1) ELSE (Resources\Sound\SWPlayer.exe "Locked.wav")
```

This is a ONE LINE code. Thanks - Geo Skionfinschii

EDIT: It is a script to test if you have gone to that area - It does work.  BUT not in the game:      '  The Error Is:       ***ELSE IS NOT EXPECTED AT THIS TIME***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF %0x-1Seen%
```

within a batch, `%0` will be replaced by the executable-name; the `0x-1Seen` will not be seen as a variable (same for %1..%9 - parameters 1..9 to the batch process)

Tip 1 : Don't use initial numerics in variables

Tip2: "quote"  user-input when testing for keystrings. `if /i "%move%"=="north"` for instance (assuming that `move` is a user-input using set/p) - the `/i` makes the match case-insensitive.

Comment: Umm, I want in Case Sensitive and is there a way aroundthe %0 being -thanks for the fix though. I will change it now. WIll %~0x-1Seen% work?   few lines to change now :P (About 50)

Comment: Yes - there is a way around using leading numerics - but it's easier to change your naming regime (possibly simply reverse num-x to x-num). You can use `for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%a in ('set 0x-1seen') do if %%a==1 whatever` but you'd also nee to take care of the situations where `0x-1seen` is not set and `01-seen` simply *begins* an environment variable. Much easier to change the varname, IMHO.